# Using Ag-Grid Custom Cell Editor and withStyles generated higher order component in Material UI

Tags: material-ui, ag-grid-react

I'm new to react/material-ui/ag-grid and am looking to add a Material UI component as a cell editor (via popup) using ag-grid/react.

I use the following standard line in my component files:

`export default withStyles(styles)(ControlledOpenSelect).`

which produces a higher order component that seems to break ag-grid. I perused the documentation on using ag-grid with higher order components [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-more-details/#higher-order-components) but am somewhat confused on how to use forwardRefs and the `withStyles` function in a compatible manner with ag-grid. An example would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this is related but maybe the Context is not available in your ag-grid try putting `reactNext={true}` as a prop in your AgGridReact component